# Adding active class to element in child state

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `ui-router` within my AngularJS app. I have two states, one of which is a child.

```
.state('patents', {
    url: '/patents',
    component: 'patents'
})
.state('patents.patent', {
    url: '/{patentId}',
    component: 'patent'
})
```

In the parent state (`patents`), I have a table with a column with dynamic buttons, some which direct users to separate states, but one needs to direct the user to tab content, which is third in the `ul` within the child state `patents.patent`.

```
//Child state

<div class="view-tabs">
    <ul class="nav view-pills">
        <li ng-click="activeSelectedTab = 0; $ctrl.activePatentItemMenu = 'Patent Info'" ng-class="{active : $ctrl.activePatentItemMenu === 'Patent Info'}">Patent Info</li>
        <li ng-click="activeSelectedTab = 1; $ctrl.activePatentItemMenu = 'Cost Analysis'" ng-class="{active : $ctrl.activePatentItemMenu === 'Cost Analysis'}">Cost Analysis</li>
        <li ng-click="activeSelectedTab = 2; $ctrl.activePatentItemMenu = 'Renewal History'" ng-class="{active : $ctrl.activePatentItemMenu === 'Renewal History'}">Renewal History</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<uib-tabset type="pills" active="activeSelectedTab">
//ALL TAB CONTENT WHICH IS DISPLAY APPROPRIATELY
</uib-tabset>
```

In the controller, `activePatentItemMenu` is set to `Patent Info`, so the first `li` item and its content is the first thing anyone sees, which is the default. I need the `active` class to be set to the 3rd `li` item `Renewal History` only if the user clicks on the specified button in the table, labeled `renewal history`.

***Question***

How do I set an `active` state to the third `li` item in the child state, only when a specific button is clicked in the parent state?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using ui-sref and ui-sref-active

```
<ul class="nav view-pills">
  <li ui-sref-active="active">
    <a ui-sref="patents.patent({patentId: 'Patent Info'})">Patent Info</a>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Then use state.params in your controller to find the active uib-tabset